# How to obtain an MRUnit 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT jar built using the hadoop1 classifier?

Tags: build, hadoop, mrunit

The latest release of MRUnit is 0.9. This release does not support DistributedCache. 
This https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-98 shows that 1.0.0 supports DistributedCache. I want to get ahold of an MRUnit 1.0.0 jar that is built for hadoop1, but I cannot find one. So I tried to build it myself, but the required jars are missing from the maven repo.

Here is the command I'm using:
`mvn package -DenvClassifier=hadoop1 -DspecificHadoopVersion=1.0.3`

It fails with dependency errors. I can get ahold of the required jars manually, but I don't know how to get the build to use them.

How can I get ahold of the jar I want (either build it myself, or download it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after I posted the question.

The answer is simple. Checkout the hadoop1 branch, and build that:

```
$ git checkout -b local/trunk-hadoop1 remotes/origin/trunk-hadoop1
$ mvn package
```